# show and render methods

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have loading screen that loads all my game levels and pass the current level to the play screen

Player should click at play button on menu screen to move to this loading screen but when he clicks it takes long time since I have multiple levels

So I tried to make animation by moving a screenshot of menu screen away from screen and moving loading screen instead of it but I have the same problem since show method is called one time before render()

My question is:

How can I load levels after animation is finished in other words how can I wait do something only one time in show(I can't load levels every frame if I put loadLevels in render) after something else has done.

Here is my code:

```
public class LoadingScreen extends BaseScreen {

    SpriteBatch batch;
    TweenManager manager;
    Sprite loading;
    Level lvl;
    int currentLevel;

    public LoadingScreen(GameMain gameMain, Sprite prvScreenSprite, int currentLevel) {
        super(gameMain, prvScreenSprite);
        this.currentLevel = currentLevel;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        manager = new TweenManager();
        Tween.registerAccessor(Sprite.class, new SpriteAccessor());
        loading = Assets.initSprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("loading.png")));
        loading.setBounds(0, 0, Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT);

        //screen animation
        if (prvScreenSprite != null) {
            Timeline.createParallel().beginParallel(
                .push(Tween.set(prvScreenSprite, SpriteAccessor.POS_XY).target(0, 0))
                .push(Tween.to(prvScreenSprite, SpriteAccessor.POS_XY, 1.5f). target(-Constants.WIDTH, 0).delay(0.1f))
                .push(Tween.set(loading, SpriteAccessor.POS_XY).target (Constants.WIDTH, 0).end().start(manager);
         }
         if(animationFinished()) {
             loadAssets();
             JsonLevel.loadLevels();
             lvl = JsonLevel.levels.get(currentLevel);
             gameMain.setScreen(new PlayScreen(gameMain, lvl, currentLevel));
        }
    }

    public void loadAssets() {
        // loading asset
    }

     @Override
     public void render(float delta) {
         manager.update(delta);
         animationFinished();

         batch.begin();
         prvScreenSprite.draw(batch);
         loading.draw(batch);
         batch.end();
     }

     public boolean animationFinished() {
         if(loading.getX() == 0) {
             return true;
         } else return false; }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to move

```
    if(animationFinished()) {
         loadAssets();
         JsonLevel.loadLevels();
         lvl = JsonLevel.levels.get(currentLevel);
         gameMain.setScreen(new PlayScreen(gameMain, lvl, currentLevel));
    }
```

branch to the `render` method to check whether the animation is finished in every frame - if it is you should load level then set new screen